# Buoyant force on the closed hollow object with trapped air submerged into the water

Tags: buoyancy

I need help to understand the buoyant force action on the hollow object with trapped air submerged into the water. Does the BF equal to the volume of the hollow section of the object multiplied by the density of the water? If not, please, explain how do the BF is defined.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "submerged", do you mean totally submerged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bouyant force acting on an object can be calculated by integrating $\oint{P}d\vec{A}$ over the surface of the whole body which is rather complicated (Note that $d\vec{A}$ is directed inwards into the body).

However, we can avoid this by using the following argument.

Consider a volume of water identical in geometry (that is, of the same shape and size as the object to be immersed). This volume can be thought of as being in equilibrium since the movement of water molecules is completely random (there is no net movement of molecules in any one direction). This suggests that the surrounding water molecules are exerting a net force equal to the weight of the considered volume of water.

Now, once we have established this, we can further argue that if we replace the same volume of water with the object under consideration, then the surrounding water molecules will exert the same amount of force that they were exerting on the previously considered volume of water.

From this follows the famous Archimedes principle which states that the buoyant force on an object immersed in water is equal to the weight of water displaced by the object, thus suggesting that this force is independent of the material of the object immersed.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The BF is the weight of the volume of water  which is equal to the volume of the object, it does not matter  if you have air or something else or nothing in the (closed) object,

Comment: So if we have, for example, a closed hollow sylinder, then I need to calculate the volume of this cylinder (the volume of the cross-section) and then to multiply by the density of the water?

Comment: The buoyant force on a body equals the weight of the water displaced by the body. Here you would calculate the volume of the fraction of the hollow cylinder submerged and multiply it with the weight density of the water.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the buoyant force is the weight of the volume of water displaced by the object.

In this case, since the object is presumably totally submerged, the above volume is the *total* volume of the hollow object, that is, the volume of the shell plus the volume of the air contained.

Consequently, only if the volume of the shell is negligible, will the buoyant force equal the volume of the hollow section of the object (the air) multiplied by the density of the water.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone for explaing the concept of BF and help.
I appreciate it.